# RestEasy Jettison JAXB/JSon output issue

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, resteasy, jettison, badgerfish

I am developing a Java EE webapp using JBoss AS 7 and Resteasy. I would like to do the Communication with the Rest Interface using the Jettison JAXB/JSon Provider.

As a demo I implemented the following JAXB annotated class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class TestJson
{
    @XmlElement
    public int      id      = 1;

    @XmlElement
    public String   name    = "hello";

    public TestJson()
    {}

}
```

To get the object I implemented the following webservice:

```
@BadgerFish
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public TestJson getJSON()
{

    return new TestJson();


}
```

now if I do the GET request I get the following response:

```
!!com.example.TestJson {id: 1, name: hello}
```

I would be expecting

```
{"id":1, "name":"hello"}
```

am I doing something wrong here? (unmarshalling JSON Objects works like a charm)

thanks for any hints.

Comment: Try using Jackson as your JAXB implementation output writer.

Comment: thanks. worked like a charm!!